# How to run python script via url using Flask

Tags: python, flask

What I want to do is run a python script(has nothing to do with html) via a url and display the result in the browser. The output can be as simple as an addition answer. 
Whatever research I am doing shows I need Apache, cgi, Flask etc. 
What I wanted to know is, can I do the aforementioned without using Apache or anything like that. Can I only use Flask to do the above task?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Apache

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Run with:

```
python my_file.py
```

And check `localhost:5000`, you should see "Hello World"

Comment: Hey Akavall, what i want to do is print the output of a python file instead of Hello World.